# PowerShell window launches then closes immediately

Tags: powershell, windows-8.1

When I start PowerShell, it launches and the the window it opens in closes immediately.

I tried taking a screenshot and it says there's a registry error:

> Reading the value of registry key
>   SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngi ne\PowerShellVersion
>   causes the following Win32 error:   The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

Why is this happening?

I'm running Windows 8.1.

Comment: What the error says exactly? Have you inspected system log?

Comment: Reading the value of registry key SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngi
ne\PowerShellVersion causes the following Win32 error:
  The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Why is this getting down voted? Sounds like a potential corrupt registry problem, and deserves actual help, not whiney down voting.

Ibrahim, are you running a script file, or opening a file in the ISE, or just attempting to open the PS Console or ISE? Some more detail about exactly what process you are going through would help track down the issue.

Comment: just trying to open the power shell nothing else  :( , also the powershell_ise gives program stopped working directly after clicking on it

Comment: how about Run -> `powershell.exe -noexit`

Comment: Getting the same error , i am using windows 8.1

Answer (score -16, accepted):

i just fixed the problem by adding the registery keys manually

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: @IbraHim Remember the point of this site is to create answers that others can use.  Your answer here is not useful without more detail.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone else is having this issue...
I tried everything on this forum as well as Microsoft's.

Ended up being an issue with my ISE profile loading `$moduleBrowser` that kept crashing ISE after startup `[Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1]`.

Try launching ISE with no profile using `powershell_ise.exe -noprofile`. Then, open your `PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`. Comment it out, save it, close ISE.

Then try re-opening ISE, load your "commented-out" `PowerShellISE_profile.ps1`, step through your profile to see what is causing the failure.

Comment: And if, like me, you use PowerShell infrequently then this might help to find the profile location (different for x86 and x64): `$PROFILE | Format-List -Force`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was just closing in like a second after starting and I wasn't seeing any errors.

- Start command prompt as Administrator
- run sfc /scannow

That fixed it for me.

I found it here - there were few more suggestions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40j4Mxt24PY